# How to Fill ListBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I think my question is basic but I can't find the way to do this issue in Asp.Net MVC 3.

I have a Model with the Controller called "Concepto". I want to see into the Create view, a ListBox with all the data from Concepto model.

The Index view show the complete data from the model, so the database connection and EF process are correct.

Comment: You should have a look at some of the tutorials [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc).  Passing data around is very fundamental and important to understand to avoid constant headaches.

Comment: When you say ListBox are you refering to a DropDownList?

Comment: No, I refer to a TextBox with multiple lines. But I think I could do it with a DropDownList. What is the Razor instruction I should use?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should create a strongly typed view using the model. Once you have the model in the context of the view, you can use the MVC helpers to render the data. For example if you have multi line postal address data stored in a property PostalAddress, you can use

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m. PostalAddress)
```

You can further customise the text area by providing col and row information as the second parameter

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m. PostalAddress, new {@cols=”50”, @rows=”20”})
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can't display all the data in a ListBox. However, you can have a field as List itme's display text and another as its value (like ID) using `@Html.ListBoxFor()` method which expects a name of a field and a collection of item eg.  `@Html.ListBoxFor(model => m.someId, Model.CollectionData);`

Thanks,